# Set fixed header scrollable content css only html table

Tags: html, css, jsp

I need an html table with fixed header and scrollable content. I am working using spring and jsp. The code is something like

```
<table class="resultsTable" border="1" bordercolor="grey" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height = "50%">
<thead class="fixedHeader">
  <tr>
            <th width="20%">Name</th>
            <th width="20%">Parameter1</th>
            <th width="20%">Parameter1</th>
            <th width="20%">Parameter1</th>
            <th width="20%">Parameter1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="scrollContent">
        <c:forEach var=" object" items="${objectsList}"
            varStatus="loopStatus">
            <tr class="${loopStatus.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                <td width="20%">${ object.name}</td>
                <td width="20%">${ object.param1}</td>
                <td width="20%">${ object.param2}</td>
                <td width="20%">${ object.param3}</td>
                <td width="20%">${ object.param4}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and css is

```
table.resultsTable {
  width: 900px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

thead.fixedHeader tr {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

tbody.scrollContent {
  display: block;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
   }
```

What i expect is column width must be the same. But I get columns with decreasing widths ie. column1 has greatest width and then goes on reducing. 5 th column being smallest width. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

please remove the width attribute form both tbody and thead.
Also remove the width  attribute in  as you have already set the width in 
 means 20% width of the table i.e. 20% of 900px.

Comment: sorry..i didnt get what u r trying to say

Comment: <th width="20%">Name</th> you have mentioned 20% over here. So remove the width attribute from <td width="20%">${ object.name}</td>. Also remove width from thead and tbody in css.

Comment: i should set width for only th and not the td?